# Streaming alsa pcm speaker output from a python application

Tags: python, linux, alsa

been doing some research for a project and wondering how I am able to stream the raw data from my alsa device to a python/C++/java application. I have been messing around with alsaaudio, the python interface, but can only do this with microphone. I am hoping to just capture all data coming through the card (from applications like vlc etc.)

Anyone help on this one?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you require the audio data also to be played to the speakers?

Comment: yeah, ideally it will be like a daemon that runs and just does processing on the audio in the background.

Comment: You mean, what is played is not the original data?

Comment: No, it's the same data just want to tie into it to use it for some other application. So essentially just tying into the driver and streaming everything that comes out of it into a buffer (but still have it play whatever is streaming out on my speakers), so that I can use it for some other reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is hardware that can reroute its output back to some capture device, but most sound devices do not support this.

You could load the [snd-aloop driver](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix%3aModule-aloop) and create a virtual device using the [multi plugin](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html#pcm_plugins_multi) to route the output to both the actual device and the loopback device, but it is likely that the sample clocks of the two devices will diverge if they are running for too long.

I would recommend to create a virtual device using the [file plugin](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html#pcm_plugins_file) to copy the data to your application through a pipe.
Put something like the following into `/etc/asound.conf` or into your `~/.asoundrc`:

```perl
pcm.mydevice {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type file
        slave.pcm "hw:0,0"   # or whatever your actual output device is
        file "|/some/where/myapplication"
    }
}
```

and tell the other applications to use ALSA device `mydevice`.